# Apache rewrite rule deletes query string

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite URLs so that they don't have the index.php in them in Apache. Everything has been working fine so far, but I needed to send querystring parameters in a GET request and realized they were being stripped off. I'm using the QSA flag, but it's not working and my query string never gets to the server.

```
<VirtualHost noomo.jp:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/noomo-web/public
<Directory "/var/www/noomo-web/public">
AllowOverride All
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/noomo.jp/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/noomo.jp/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerName noomo.jp
</VirtualHost>
```

Am I missing something required to pass the query string through? I've looked all over Google, but everything I can find just refers to redirecting based on the query string, not making sure that the query string gets through. I've had this same thing happen on an nginx server before, but I don't know how to fix it on Apache.

Comment: Can you add R flag also (`[L,QSA,R]`), and check what is the exact result of your rule?

Comment: I added the R flag and it didn't make any difference, the query string is still gone and I tested it with a one-off PHP script that just echoed the query string. However, if I do add the index.php part to the URL it works fine. What am I doing in my rewrite that's stripping the query string?

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Found it! Alright, I'm gonna answer my own question so people will see this if they Google the same problem, cause this took me hours to realize... Apparently you can't put rewrites inside the  entry or they won't work right. I moved the rewrite rules out and put them right inside the  entry and it works now.